# xml parsing of special charactor using dom in android

Tags: android, xml

I have following xml but when I parse it parser breaks at '&' and I got only android. How can I 
get android & iphone as a result ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<summary>android&amp;iphone</summary>
```

Comment: what kind of parser do you use? Your xml is valid and should work. You can check xml markup [online](http://validator.w3.org/check). I think that something wrong with your parser.

Comment: I am using Dom parser and xml is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending data from server, switch "&" with something like "##AND##" and reswitch at client side